# Winapi.ShLwApi.StrFormatByteSize64 treats my app as a DLL

Tags: delphi, winapi, filesize, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, When trying to use `Winapi.ShLwApi.StrFormatByteSize64` to convert an `Int64` file-size value into a formatted string I get a runtime error:

```
var
  ThisSize: Int64;
  pszBuf: PWideChar;
  cchBuf: Cardinal;

Winapi.ShLwApi.StrFormatByteSize64(ThisSize, pszBuf, cchBuf);
```

Error message:

> --------------------------- MyApp.exe - Entry point not found
> --------------------------- The Procedure Entry point "StrFormatByteSize64W" was not found in the DLL
> "C:\DELPHI\MyApp\Win32\Debug\MyApp.exe".
> --------------------------- OK
>
> ---

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is likely related to the following warning in the [function's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strformatbytesize64a): "StrFormatByteSize64 can be used for either ANSI or Unicode characters. However, while StrFormatByteSize64A can be called directly, StrFormatByteSize64W is not defined. When StrFormatByteSize64 is called with a Unicode value, StrFormatByteSizeW is used."

Comment: You say that you get a compile error, but that looks like a runtime error. Which is it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Uhmm, I think it was a runtime error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [remarks for the function in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strformatbytesize64a) say:

> StrFormatByteSize64 can be used for either ANSI or Unicode characters. However, while StrFormatByteSize64A can be called directly, StrFormatByteSize64W is not defined. When StrFormatByteSize64 is called with a Unicode value, StrFormatByteSizeW is used.

The Delphi import is declared as:

```
function StrFormatByteSize64; external shlwapi32 name 'StrFormatByteSize64W';
```

In other words, this is a translation error in the Delphi RTL. The function `StrFormatByteSize64W` does not exist in `shlwapi.dll`.

As the documentation says, call `StrFormatByteSize` instead. This is handled for you by the Windows header files, but Embarcadero have not picked up this nuance when translating them.

This program demonstrates:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.ShLwApi;

procedure Main;
var
  ThisSize: Int64;
  szBuf: array[0..255] of Char;
  cchBuf: Cardinal;
begin
  ThisSize := Int64(1024)*1024*1024*256;
  cchBuf := Length(szBuf);
  Winapi.ShLwApi.StrFormatByteSize(ThisSize, szBuf, cchBuf);
  Writeln(szBuf);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
256 GB
```

I have reported this to Embarcadero: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29943

Comment: A very extensive and professional answer! Thanks, David!